# How to add an array based filed in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm making an app atm where I get dummy data from a json file. My filed in this file looks like this:

```js
 {
  "model": "card.model",
  "pk": 2222,
  "fields": {
    "meal_1": 5555,
    "meal_2": 5556,
    "meals": "[5555, 5556]"
  }
}

{
  "model": "meal.model",
  "pk": 5555,
  "fields": {
    "name": "Pizza",
    "vagan": True
  }
}

{
  "model": "meal.model",
  "pk": 5556,
  "fields": {
    "name": "Sandwich",
    "vagan": False
  }
}
```

I have a Meal class that contains: name, photo, description.
I have also Card class that gets info right from json file.

```js
class Card() {
  meal_1 = models.ForeignKey(
    Meal,
    related_name='meal_1"
  )
   meal_2 = models.ForeignKey(
    Meal,
    related_name='meal_2"
  )
  
  meals=[] ??
}
```

How can I add an array field that will contain a reference to these meals. What I want to achieve is loop over this meals and place into django template. Now I do this by reference to each filed: instance.meal_1.name... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Night Owl's approach is pretty good, but there is also another approach you can take. That is using [**`ManyToManyField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

In the given `JSON`, id of `meal_1` and `meal_2` are inside `meals` field. So I don't think its necessary for you to consider `meal_1` and `meal_2` when creating models(because there could be more than 2 meals). So you can try to create ManyToMany Relation between `Card` and `Meal`. Like this:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vagan = models.BooleanField()

class Card(models.Model):
    meals = models.ManyToManyField(Meal)


# usage

   meal = Meal.objects.create(name="sandwitch", vegan=False)
   card = Card.objects.create()
   card.meals.add(meal)

# template

   {% for meal in card.meals.all %}
       {{ meal.name }}
       {{ meal.vegan }}
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add Card as ForeignKey to your Meal class. Then in the template, you can loop for each Meal in the Card.

**meal.py**

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    ...
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    ...
```

**template.html**

```
{% for meal in card.meal_set %}
   {{ meal.name }}
{% endfor %}
```